# Comparing each element of the array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to answer a question of the algorithm from using c++ language. The question is compare each element of the two arrays and give a score. Basically compare the first element of the first array with the first element of the second array and give some score. If the first element of the first array is bigger than the first element of the second array, the first array receive one score. In the end return output with the sum of the score of this two arrays.

I did this but unfortunately this code aren't giving me which I expect answer.

```
#include <iostream>

int array_a[3] = { 6, 4, 6};
int array_b[3] = { 5, 4, 10};
int array_output[2] = {};


int main()
{          
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++) //z is for array_output[2]
            {
                if (array_a[i] > array_b[j])
                {
                    array_output[z]++; //if int array_a[0] is bigger than int array_b[0] the first element of the output[0] receive +1
                }
                else if (array_a[i] == array_b[j])
                {
                    array_output[z] = 0;//if the int array_a[1] and int array_b[1] are equal anyone receive score
                }
                else if (array_a[i] < array_b[j])
                {
                    array_output[z]++; //if int array_a[2] is less than int array_b[2] the second element of the array_output receive +1
                }
                else
                {

                }

            }
        }
    }
        std::cout << "{" << array_output[0] << " , " << array_output[1] << "}";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

inputs int array_a[3] = {6, 4, ,6} and int array_b[3] = {5, 4, ,10}

I expect the output array_output[2] = {1,1}.

With this code the are returning array_output[2] = {4,4}

Comment: Your problem is less than clear. Please provide an example of what result you expect to see.

Comment: Also, you don't need three nested loops to compare the arrays.  You can do it in one.

Comment: Just guessing but is this something you are expecting: `#include <iostream>

int array_a[3] = {4, 5, 6};
int array_b[3] = {4, 6, 10};
int array_output[2] = {};

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (array_a[i] > array_b[i]) {
            array_output[0]++;
        } else if (array_a[i] < array_b[i]) {
            array_output[1]++;
        } else {
            // equal, no change in score
        }
    }
    std::cout << "{" << array_output[0] << " , " << array_output[1] << "}\n";
    return 0;
}`? It will output `{0, 2}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a.first with b.first, a.second with b.second, and so on, then a single loop should be enough; and if you are just interested in the sums, even the result array is superfluous:

```
int main() {

    int array_a[3] = { 4, 5, 6};
    int array_b[3] = { 4, 6, 10};
    int sum_a=0, sum_b=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (array_a[i] > array_b[i]) {
            sum_a++;
        } else if (array_b[i] > array_a[i])
            sum_b++;
    }

    std::cout << "sum a:" << sum_a << "; sum b:" << sum_b << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Although the problem statement is not quite clear, it seems from OP's code that he wants to compare every element of first array with every element of second array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 

void compare(int array_a[], int array_b[]); //Function prototype

int main()
{
    int array_al[3] = { 6, 4, 6 }; // array inputs
    int array_bo[3] = { 5, 4, 10 };

    compare(array_al, array_bo); //call the function compare

    return 0;
}

void compare(int array_a[], int array_b[])
{
    int al = 0, bo = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) // read and compare the values until reach the numbers of the elements
    {
        if (array_a[j] > array_b[j])
        {
            al++;
        }
        else if (array_a[j] < array_b[j])
        {
            bo++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "{" << al << " , " << bo << "}"; // print out the sum of the values
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```